# How can I get the same return value as solidity `abi.encodePacked` in Golang

Tags: go, ethereum, solidity

How can i run abi.encodePacked in golang?

in solidity i use `keccak256(abi.encodePacked(a, b))` to calc the signature of the params.

here is my contract.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/ECRecovery.sol";


contract MyContract {
    using ECRecovery for bytes32;
    address permittedSinger;

    function doSomething(
    bytes32 id, uint256 amount, bytes sig
    ) {
        bytes32 hash = getHash(msg.sender, id, amount);
        address msgSigner = hash.recover(sig);
        require(msgSigner == permittedSinger);
    }

    function getMsgSigner(bytes32 proveHash, bytes sig) public pure returns (address) {
        return proveHash.recover(sig);
    }

    function getHash(
    address receiver, bytes32 id, uint256 amount
    ) pure returns (bytes32) {
        return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(receiver, id, amount));
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I need to build some params in Golang. If someone call the contract, I want to check these params are valid.
So i have to calculate the signature of the params in Golang, then check it in Contract.

Comment: look here [go-ethereum source code](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/933972d139b0fe291cb01c7ad2c0f9d3109a68dd/accounts/abi/abi_test.go#L212)

Comment: The easiest thing to do would just be to call the smart contract's `getHash` from your Go code.

Comment: @ChihebNexus thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

finally I managed to do it. :)

```
package main

import (
    "math/big"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common/hexutil"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi"
    "log"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto/sha3"
)

func main() {
    uint256Ty, _ := abi.NewType("uint256")
    bytes32Ty, _ := abi.NewType("bytes32")
    addressTy, _ := abi.NewType("address")

    arguments := abi.Arguments{
        {
            Type: addressTy,
        },
        {
            Type: bytes32Ty,
        },
        {
            Type: uint256Ty,
        },
    }

    bytes, _ := arguments.Pack(
        common.HexToAddress("0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"),
        [32]byte{'I','D','1'},
        big.NewInt(42),
    )

    var buf []byte
    hash := sha3.NewKeccak256()
    hash.Write(bytes)
    buf = hash.Sum(buf)

    log.Println(hexutil.Encode(buf))
    // output:
    // 0x1f214438d7c061ad56f98540db9a082d372df1ba9a3c96367f0103aa16c2fe9a
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work the same for dynamic length types (like `bytes`). Go's `arguments.Pack` will return what you get from `abi.encode` not `abi.encodePacked`.

Comment: go-ethereum 1.9.7 has a few more args in `abi.NewType`. The above still work with ```abi.NewType("uint256", "uint256", nil)```

Comment: what if an array like two addresses?

Answer (score 5):

As `Jakub N` is said in comments to accepted answer, `Go's arguments.Pack` returns as `abi.encode` and not `abi.encodePacked`. In your case it works because all packed values are 32 bytes, but if you also add some strings then the result will be different.

Here is how to do it to be compatible with **tightly** packed encoding corresponding to `abi.encodePacked`:

```golang
// hash of packed byte array with arguments

hash := crypto.Keccak256Hash(
        common.HexToAddress("0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000").Bytes(),
        [32]byte{'I','D','1'},
        common.LeftPadBytes(big.NewInt(42).Bytes(), 32),
        []byte("Some other string value"),
    )

// normally we sign prefixed hash
// as in solidity with `ECDSA.toEthSignedMessageHash`

prefixedHash := crypto.Keccak256Hash(
        []byte(fmt.Sprintf("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n%v", len(hash))),
        hash.Bytes(),
    )

// sign hash to validate later in Solidity

sig, err := crypto.Sign(prefixedHash.Bytes(), privateKey)
```

It is also more efficient as we don't pack and allocate additional memory for that. Hash function iterates over existing values.